# Retrieve server side data using XMLlHttpRequest in javascript and populate the items in newly created li element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am kinda new to javascript and trying to learn some basic operation. I have a dynamically created li element where a list of notes are being displayed.

Adding notes to the server is working well. Each note has an id and name value. The jason object is stored in this form `[{"id":"1","name":"This is the first note"}]`.

Now I want to retrieve the list from the server and display only the "name" values as the list on the same page whenever the user leaves the page and open the page again.

The controller function looks like this:

```
public class NoteController {

    private List<Note> notes;

    public NoteController() {
        this.notes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Note> noteList() {
        return this.notes;
    }
}
```

Heres the html code:

```
       <form>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="addNote();" value="Add"/>
        </form>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
        function loadNotes() {

            var HttpGET = new XMLHttpRequest();
            HttpGET.open("GET", "url", true);
            HttpGET.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (HttpGET.readyState === 4) {
                    if (HttpGET.status === 200) {

                    var response = JSON.parse(HttpGET.responseText);
                    var loadListElement = document.createElement("li");

                 loadListElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("name"));
                                                         document.querySelector("#notes").appendChild(loadListElement);
                    document.querySelector("#notes").innerHTML = response.value.notes;
                    }
                }
            }

            HttpGET.send(null);
        }
```

The javascript code is not working. The Json data should be displayed inside the ul element within its child node li. But I see nothing when I close the page or reload. I think I am not sure if I have used the response value properly in the loadTasks function. Also I am note sure if I have created text node properly in document.createTextNode("name"). Or am I missing something? Please help me to get through this. I spent quite much time on this already and cant think anything else other than banging my head here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you sure `http://localhost:8080/` is the correct url to your get action? You need to show us the response you are getting. Use `console.log()` for that. I think you need to iterate over the response to show the list of notes. Also, `document.createTextNode("name")` should be `document.createTextNode(response.value.notes)` but again this will depend on the response structure

Comment: Then looks like response is not in proper format. Try using `console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)` to get the original respone

Comment: However the console.log(xmlHttp.responseText) shows an empty array []. After I inserts two notes like Running, Sleeping then it console shows the response like this [{"id":"9d0962e8-e1f5-4b61-85ed-489dbc6d5bb2","name":"Running"},{"id":"82e1ad1a-9bfb-490f-8f95-90139dfe6790","name":"Sleeping"}]

Comment: Index:44 points to the line where  loadListElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("name")); is but I have changed to loadListElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("response.value.tasks")); based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Anu this is my current progress. I used a for loop to iterate through the response message but the app crashes crashes on the for loop. The crash report says The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. The line number given on the error points to the for loop.

Comment: Can you try my answer posted below. Also can you check the `console.log(response)` for my code

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments I assume you are getting response in the following format

```
    [
      {"id":"9d0962e8-e1f5-4b61-85ed-489dbc6d5bb2","name":"Runnin‌​g"},
      {"id":"82e1ad1a-‌​9bfb-490f-8f95-90139‌​dfe6790","name":"Sle‌​eping"}
    ]
```

Now your code should look like this

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {    
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
          if (xmlHttp.status === 200) { 
              if(xmlHttp.responseText){// check for response
                 var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                 for(var note in response){ //iterate over response object
                     if(response.hasOwnProperty(note)){ //check whether note is a property of response object
                        var loadListElement = document.createElement("li");
                        loadListElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response‌​[note].name)); //use note's name property to get actual text
                        document.querySelector("#notes").appendChild(loadListElement);//append the element
                     }
                 }

              }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to debug for the issue then. Add `console.log(response) ` and also inside the loop `console.log(note)` and `console.log(note[name])` and check the values. If you know how to add breakpoints use it to check the values

Comment: What is the output for `console.log(response)` and other variables i mentioned in the last comment? And what is `task`? Also can you check the network tab of dev tools to get the actual response your r getting for ajax request?

Comment: I got it working properly now. I used response[note].name in place of note[name] and now the textNode is receiving the value. So the line                         loadListElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(note[name]));  will look like this                         loadListElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response[note].name));  Thank you Anu so much for your kind support.